# Show that $\frac 1x \ge 3 - 2\sqrt{x}$ for all positive real numbers $x$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Show that $\frac 1x \ge 3 - 2\sqrt{x}$ for all positive real numbers $x$. Describe when we have equality.

I tried simplifying the equation but got stuck. Can someone help me simplify this inequality into one that's easier to solve the actual problem above? I don't want/need the answer to the actual problem, but just need help simplifying the inequality. (A hint would be fine.) Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: as $x$ is assumed to be positive, you could consider the change of variable $x = y^2$ with $y> 0$. Then your inequality becomes $1\geq 3y^2 -2y$.

Comment: **Hint**: For $x>1$ you can use the following fact: Let $f,g:I\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions at the open interval $I$ such that $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x\in I$, and $f(a)=g(a)$. Then $f(x)>g(x)$ for $x>a$.

Comment: For $x\geq \frac{9}{4}$ the inequality is obviously true (RHS = 0).

Comment: $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x}+2\sqrt{x}-3$ Using first derivative test what information can we obtain of the global minimum or maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*
$$\frac{1}{x} - 3 + 2\sqrt{x} = \frac{2x^{3/2} - 3x + 1}{x} = \frac{2t^3 - 3t^2 + 1}{t^2} (x = t^2)$$

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it!

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that:
$$2x\sqrt{x}-3x+1\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$2x\sqrt{x}-3x+1\geq3\sqrt[3]{(x\sqrt{x})^2\cdot1}-3x=0.$$

Comment: ... with equality iff $x\sqrt x=x\sqrt x=1\implies x=1$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** $\quad$ You have to prove

$$\frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} \geq 3$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-3+2\sqrt{x}$

Then its derivative is defined and positive real numbers and equals $f'(x)=\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}}{x^2 \sqrt{x}}$

You can easily show that $f'<0$ if $x<1$ and $f' \ge 0$ if $x\ge 1$.

Then $f$ reaches a minimum at $1$, which is $0$.

By considering the limits of $f$ at $0$ and $+\infty$, you can conclude.